# how do I implement inapp purchase iOS web app using short message

Tags: ios

Hello I hv developed a web app where users are supposed to be able to make purchase for digital goods.

I integrated stripe as payment system

after uploading my application to the iOS store I get message from the iOS store about making sure I use their in app purchase functionality to process payments.

from what I have found out I will have to develop my application in native form to be able to use such functionality app wise.

my app is built using php as it is a web app.

so my question pls is it possible to make use of an sms gateway to carry inapp purchases.

I have seen apps like baddo do these, but I have no knowledge on how this can work.

please can any profer any company or solution that provides sms for in app purchases on iOS thanks

Comment: If you are delivering an app via the App Store you must use Apple's IAP. You can't use Stripe or SMS or any other method. You need native code running on the device.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to address your concerns:

- you cannot publish the app that has only a web view and nothing else on the App Store. As soon as Apple finds out about this it will remove the app, so technically you may pass if they don't notice but your app is under the constant threat of being removed.
- you cannot sell any digital goods without using IAP inside the app.
  What you talk about is selling on your web site and activating the
  purchase in the app. You can do that. But you cannot sell inside the
  app or direct users to your web site to purchase. They must have
  already made a purchase on the web site.
- while you must use the native code for IAPs, you can invoke that code from your web view, so you don't need a fully native app for that